# Returning the value of a function with out assigning it to a variable

Tags: c#

So What I am trying to do is take a list of user inputs and place them directly into an array. I would like to do this without assigning a variable to each input because there could be hundreds.

```
        static void writeAndWait(String statement, int millisecondsToWait)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(statement);
        Thread.Sleep(millisecondsToWait);
        return;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //I am using ArrayLists because they will store as many values as needed wether it be 1 or 1,000,000 or more
        ArrayList Name; //Declaring Name  
        ArrayList Time; //Declaring Time
        ArrayList Path; //Declaring Path
        Name = new ArrayList(); //Name will be used to store the names of the timers the user inputs
        Time = new ArrayList(); //Time will be used to store the times of the timers the user inputs
        Path = new ArrayList(); //Path will be used to store the path line of the timers the user inuts;

        writeAndWait("Hello, if you want to add timers all you need to do is type a name and press enter, say how long you want the timer to run for in minutes, and then add a number 1-10 any timers with the same number at the end will run sycrnasly, and any timers with diferant nubers will run async", 2000);
        Name.Add(Console.ReadKey().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Name[0]);
    }
```

The Console.WriteLine just returns 'Console.ReadKey().ToString())

I would like it to return the key that the user inputs. Or the return value of Console.ReadKey

Comment: FYI, you probably want to use [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Console.ReadKey`

Comment: Why not use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`?  Also why are you using `Console.ReadKey` instead of `Console.ReadLine` since your message says to type a name and press enter?

Comment: I was just using ReadKey as a test. I was having some trouble reading values out of a list which is why I switched to ArrayLists. If you could comment some code in  showing how to use the List<String> that would be great. But is still have the question how do I only return the value not the acctuall command?

Comment: bool quit = false;
            var names = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter names.");
            while(!quit)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == string.Empty)
                    quit = true;
                else
                    names.Add(input);
            }

Comment: /* you can add this to display the names  */
            Console.WriteLine("You entered this names:");
            foreach(string name in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }

Comment: you need to have using System.Collections.Generic; Sorry I don't post this as an answer cause I don't want this kind of stuff in my history. If anyone else want, feel free to re-post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking here, but using a struct will prevent you from needing to maintain separate arrays.  If you actually have a dynamic number of arguments, I can modify this answer for that.

```
public struct TimerDescriptor
{
    public string Name;
    public string Time;
    public string Path;

    public static bool TryParse(string text, out TimerDescriptor value)
    {
        //check for empty text
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            value = default(TimerDescriptor);
            return false;
        }

        //check for wrong number of arguments
        var split = text.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (split.Length != 3)
        {
            value = default(TimerDescriptor);
            return false;
        }

        value = new TimerDescriptor
        {
            Name = split[0],
            Time = split[1],
            Path = split[2]
        };

        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + ' ' + Time + ' ' + Path;
    }
}

static void writeAndWait(String statement, int millisecondsToWait)
{
    Console.WriteLine(statement);
    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsToWait);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //I am using ArrayLists because they will store as many values as needed wether it be 1 or 1,000,000 or more
    var timerDescriptors = new List<TimerDescriptor>();

    writeAndWait("Hello, if you want to add timers all you need to do is type a name and press enter, say how long you want the timer to run for in minutes, and then add a number 1-10 any timers with the same number at the end will run sycrnasly, and any timers with diferant nubers will run async", 2000);

    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    TimerDescriptor descriptor;
    if (TimerDescriptor.TryParse(line, out descriptor))
    {
        timerDescriptors.Add(descriptor);
        Console.WriteLine(descriptor);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Syntax error: wrong number of arguments.  The syntax is: {Name} {Time} {Path} without the curly braces.");
}
```